# Rails 3: PDF generation with wicked_pdf suddenly does not work anymore ? [undefined method `virtual_path']

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, pdf, wicked-pdf

Our platform has been online for a while and working just fine. Our customers are able to download their invoices in PDF format just fine.

We've been working on a upgrades for a few month, and just today we noticed that "suddenly" non of our PDF generation with wicked_pdf and wkhtmltopdf no longer worked...

I have absolutely no idea why, I checked everything I could think of:
- routes
- initializers
- gems
- etc.

Everything seems to be fine, same as the actual only version.

We have not changed Rails or Ruby version. Everything is pretty much the same:
- Ruby 1.8.7 REE
- Rails 3.0.10

The error we are getting is:

```
Rendered groups/clients/proforma.pdf.haml (103.4ms)
Sent data toto.pdf (2.7ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 6892ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `virtual_path' for text template:ActionView::Template::Text):
  app/controllers/groups/clients_controller.rb:980:in `proforma'
  app/controllers/groups/clients_controller.rb:976:in `proforma'
  lib/include/flash_session_cookie_middleware.rb:16:in `call'
  lib/include/flash_session_cookie_middleware.rb:16:in `call'
```

The controller looks like:

```
  def proforma
    @request = WireRequest.where(:_id => params[:id], :status => :pending).first

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {render :layout => false}  
      format.pdf do
        unless @request.nil?"
          render(:pdf => "PROFORMA_#{@request.invoice_num}", :layout => 'pdf')                
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Any ideas of what could be going wrong? I have no more ideas :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already had this kind of issue using the new relic rpm for developers.

I forked the gem [here](https://github.com/apneadiving/rpm).